# Top in Stack Implementation

Tags: arrays, initialization, stack

In the array implementation of stacks, in the initialization step, do we have to take the top value as 0 or -1?

There are books initializing top with 0 and some with -1. Which one is right and to be followed? In my intuition, I think initializing top = -1 is better as we are not wasting memory for one unit of data. Is my intuition, right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order in which you insert data and increment/decrement the stack pointer. If, when pushing, you start by inserting the data and then increasing the pointer, the top of the stack would be 0, as the first operation is placing the data in the first slot. But when it's done the other way around, that being increasing the pointer and then inserting data, the top would be -1, as it needs to first be increased to zero to get to the slot in question.